# SetText Value of Current System Volume

Tags: java, android, xml

i have this code and i would like to set text in the various TextView that says the current volume level. Example: System Volume: 35%. Obviously, this number has to change when I "move" the SeekBar. This is the code.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity_JellyBean extends DashBoardActivity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
    private SeekBar alarmSeekbar = null;
    private SeekBar systemSeekbar = null;
    private SeekBar notificationSeekbar = null;
    private SeekBar ringSeekbar = null;


    private AudioManager audioManager = null; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jellybean);


        initControls();

    }

    private void initControls()
    {


        try
        {


            volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            alarmSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
            systemSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
            notificationSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar4);
            ringSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar5);

            final TextView media = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView ring = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView alarm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            TextView noti = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            TextView ringe = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);



            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));  

            alarmSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
            alarmSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));  

            systemSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM));
            systemSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM));   

            notificationSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
            notificationSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)); 

            ringSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
            ringSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));  

            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {

                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });

            alarmSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });

            systemSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });

            notificationSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });

            ringSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it you're not sure how to do?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It seems you've got everything here to do it.  All you do is set the text for your `TextView` inside your `OnSeekBarChangeListener()`.